# LTK button height not configurable

Tags: common-lisp, ltk

I'm using LTK for basic windows in Common Lisp. I want to create a square button, but it turns out that height can't be changed. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
(let ((tile (make-instance 'button
                           :width 20
                           :height 20))))
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid initialization argument:
  :HEIGHT
in call for class #<STANDARD-CLASS LTK:BUTTON>.
See also:
  The ANSI Standard, Section 7.1.2
  [Condition of type INITARG-ERROR]
```

In the [LTK documentation](http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/ltkdoc.pdf), height is listed as configurable for buttons. Is there something wrong with the installation or is it a known bug or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is missing on ltk side. With `M-.` in Slime I go to the definition of button:

```
(defargs button (widget)
  command
  compound
  default
  image
  state
  textvariable
  underline
  width)
```

There is no `height` indeed and it doesn't come from `widget`.

I asked on nodgui (ltk fork with syntax sugar and more meta-widgets) because the maintainer is real nice: https://notabug.org/cage/nodgui/issues/6

His answer:

---

nodgui supports only the widget that use 'ttk' theme engine:

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_intro.htm

the documentation for ttk::button:

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_button.htm

shows no height parameter (correct me if I am wrong)

(is there a chance that you are looking at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/button.htm ? This is the non-ttk version of the widget and is not supported)

Probably you can play with frame and sticky attribute to modify the geometry of a button (never tried), moreover I do not know about a way to specify the size of a button in pixel units.

Hope this helps someway! :)

ps: Probably is important to point out that the LTK documentation is outdated in the widget part.

---

Other information to consider: https://mailman.common-lisp.net/pipermail/ltk-user/2016-June/000625.html

> Tcl/Tk up to 8.4
>   including allowed the font for buttons to be set. From 8.5 there was the
>   ttk widget set, which at some point became the default for ltk. The ttk
>   widget set uses a theme engine to determine many of the rendering
>   parameters for widgets to achieve a "native" look. This means that a lot of
>   older options for the widgets got removed. You can find the documentation
>   for the widget here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_button.htm
>
> If you push :tk84 onto *features*, you get the old style widgets, otherwise
>   you can of course create/modify ttk themes, that should give you the
>   ability to configure fonts too. With bug reports like this, it also would
>   be very helpful if you included information about the operation system the
>   problem shows, the lisp you are using Ltk with, and in this case, a screen
>   shot.