# Ltk button configuration

Tags: common-lisp, ltk

I originally only had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504488/ltk-button-height-not-configurable) setting the height of buttons, but as it turns out, configuring in general has problems. I can change the width, text, and commands of buttons, but nothing else (such as color or relief). The documentation is inconsistent with the possible keys emacs shows. For example, emacs shows no height key, while in the documentation it is present.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, show code please. Also I don't see the link with emacs. Is it an emacs-related question only ?

Comment: Code is in the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LTK button height not configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504488/ltk-button-height-not-configurable)